# Querying data using Python's requests returns status code 512

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to query trader portfolios, e.g.  this one: https://www.etoro.com/people/jaynemesis/portfolio

I know the basic setup should be as follows:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
data = response.json()
```

Analyzing the Request Headers tab, I set the following parameters as headers:

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
          'Host': 'www.etoro.com',
          'Referer': 'https://www.etoro.com/people/jaynemesis/portfolio/history'
          }
```

and I found the following link, together with a GET prefix indicating a GET type request in Inspect -> Network tab -> Headers tab:

```
url = https://www.etoro.com/sapi/trade-data-real/live/public/portfolios?cid=3378352&client_request_id=7a29e39e-5324-4234-bac7-d54e8fe4b5a6
```

When printing `response.status_code`, I get a status code of 512. What am I missing? Is it possible that it is not at all possible to query this data (is it perhaps blocked somehow)?

**EDIT**:

- `response.text` returns `"error":{"failureReason":"Something went wrong, please try again"}`
- `response.headers` returns a long dict starting with:
  `{'Date': 'Mon, 19 Oct 2020 14:33:14 GMT', 'Content-Length': '66', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid= ... }`

Comment: Do you get anything beyond status code `512` in `response` - what is in `response.text` and `response.headers`?

Comment: `response.text` returns `"error":{"failureReason":"Something went wrong, please try again"}` while `response.headers` returns a header dict with Date, Content-Length, Connection, Set-Cookie and many other keys.